# How do I change the colours on a figure by the image function in R?

Tags: r, heatmap

I have the following toy matrix, and I can create a visualisation, and change the colours of the tiles,

```
library(arules)    
m1 <- matrix(c(0,0,1,1,2,2), byrow=TRUE, nrow=3)
image(m1, col=heat.colors(3))
```

My question regards a sparse matrix,

```
library(Matrix)    
m2 <- Matrix(c(0,0,1,1,2,2), byrow=TRUE, sparse=TRUE, nrow=3)
```

If I attempt to create the corresponding visualisation:

```
image(m2, col=heat.colors(3))
```

I receive an error: "Error in .local(x, ...) : argument 2 matches multiple formal arguments". I believe this is because the argument 'col' is ambiguous. So, I tried to work out which other arguments that are similar to 'col' using,

```
args(image)
```

However, this provided the following output which did not include 'col' or similar agruments,

```
function (x, ...) 
NULL
```

My question is the following: How do you create an image from a sparse matrix using image() and then alter the colours of the tiles?

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to convert your sparse `Matrix` into a `matrix`:

```
image(as.matrix(m2), col=heat.colors(3))
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I'd like to perform the visualisation on a matrix of approximately 7000 x 2000. I believe using a sparse matrix may speed this up - is this true? This is why I'm keen to get it to work for sparse matrices.

Comment: @joel38237 : perhaps, but that's a totally separate question - open a new question. Anyway, the sparse matrix may need to be expanded to full for plotting, so be clear which part exactly you want to speed up - the computation of the matrix, or the plotting, or both. Avoid premature optimization unless it's demonstrably seriously slow (show runtimes).